# Designing a database not to have a huge table

Tags: database

The project I am designing is for the company I work for so I have had to think of a similar scenario that would potentially have roughly the same issue (if its an issue at all).

Right lets invent a new sport.  "Tapping consistency".  Up to 12 people can play at once.  A timer starts and goes on for 2 hours.  The players have a digital pad in front of them, they have to tap it 10 seconds after the timer starts and then every ten seconds until the timer reaches the two hour mark.

The application I need to design here is to record the statistics of this rather dull sport.  Every single tap will need to be stored and be browseable via some interface.  Here is how I thought about designing the database tables.

```
PLAYER
 - PlayerID
 - Name
 - ...

GAME
 - GameId
 - PlayDate
- ...

GAME-PLAYER
 - GameId
 - PlayerId

TAPS
 - GameId
 - PlayerId
 - TapTime
 - ...
```

So you have probably figured out the problem by now.
12 players x 800ish taps per game = 10,000ish rows in the "taps" table per game.

If this sport catches on, the taps database is going to become enormous.  Is there some whizzy db design trickery I could use to stop this from becoming a problem?

Comment: One tap, one row is totally fine and 10,000 rows totally isn't a large amount! DBS are designed to store much more data.

Depending on your queries it might be reasonable to store all 12 more-or-less-concurrent-taps together in a row (if you always access them together).

Comment: If you think your database will be very large, then hire a specialist in large database design and maintenance. There are many decisions which can affect the viablity of a database system once there are billions or more records. Databases are difficult to refactor, you need the expert from the start not 5 years down the road when nothing works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Shard your data based on games (say game id). You can create the Taps table at the runtime for a new game and name it like gameid_taps.

That way, you will not have a huge big table and your queries will work much much better.

Comment: REcommend the sharding (or partitioning) not the new table creation part.